# Asymptotic running time in Big Theta notation

Tags: asymptotics

If I have an algorithm with the running time $T(n) = 5n^4/100000 + n^3/100$, 
I know that I get Θ$(n^4)$.

Now, if I have something like $T(n) = \frac{10n^2 + 20n^4 + 100n^3}{n^4}$, does this yield Θ$(n^3)$?

I am trying to eliminate low-order terms to use the Substitution method to prove this.

Comment: The two results you mention are wrong. This seems to indicate a deep problem in your understanding of the no(ta)tion $\Theta$.

Comment: Im sorry, Stack Exchange messed up the formatting of the first example.

Comment: My comment was applying to both versions of your question. The third version replaces $\Theta(n^3)$ by $\Theta(n^4)$ in the first example, hence now my comment applies only to the second example. Can you explain why you suggest $\Theta(n^3)$? (By the way, SE messed up nothing, you did, using LaTeX improperly.)

Comment: actually, would it be Θ(1) since all members, except 20 (constant) will limit to zero when n is growing?

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $

Answer (score 1):

In your second example you have $T(n) = \Theta(1)$ as $n\to +\infty$.

Comment: What about mentioning that this assertion is resulting from the comments, which led the OP themselves to a solution?